# Recortar archivos multimedia en línea de comandos

Tags: linux, audio

Hola y gracias por leerme. Leer ya es ayudar.
Tengo unos cuantos archivos MP3 a los que quiero quitar el primer minuto. Estoy intentando hacerlo con ffmpeg de distintas maneras pero no sé qué hago mal. Intento hacerlo en modo batch porque no quiero hacerlo con los archivos de uno en uno. Estoy trabajando sobre Lubuntu con lame y ffmpeg instalados. ¿Alguien sabe la sintaxis del comando? No me importa que el comando funcione sólo para un archivo porque lo aplicaría a todos los archivos con un script.
En cualquier caso, gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, lo ideal es publicar junto a tu pregunta, el código de lo que intentas hacer, así lo tenemos mucho más sencillo a la hora de ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según tu consulta lo que buscas debe ser algo como lo siguiente:
donde `-i input.mp3` es el fichero de entrada `-ss 00:02:54.583` es el tiempo desde que se desea partir, en tu caso `-ss 00:01:00.0` y con `-acodec copy` le decimos que no lo recodifique sino lo copie tal cual y por último el nombre de fichero de salida.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ss 00:02:54.583 -acodec copy output.mp3
```

[Cortando audio](http://snipplr.com/view/68795/ffmpeg--trim-audio-file-without-reencoding/)

[Documentacion](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

[Formato tiempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Muchas gracias Maximiliano. Al final encontré otra solución que pasa por usar sox. La instalación en Linux con  apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all y luego el comando para quitar el primer minuto es `sox entrada.m4a recortado.mp3 trim 60`. Vamos, que el formato de salida puede ser el que quieras porque trata el audio después de haberlo "descomprimido" desde el archivo de entrada, lo que significa que, si el formato de salida es comprimido con pérdida de información, se perderá calidad. Y si haces un `sox entrada.m4a recortado.mp3 trim 60 fade 0:5` ya queda perfecto, porque el "fade in" hace que no sea tan brusco el corte. También se puede usar en Windows.
Lo dicho, muchas gracias.